# Returning empty fields errors for fields that were complete

Tags: php, html

I have a form for user registration where i receive first name, last name, email, password and repeat-password. I also have some validation that returns errors in the URL identifying wether the input was valid or empty. However, even though, i filled all the fields, when i attempt to submit the form, i receive the if condition for empty fields, even though everything was filled properly.

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="includes/signup.inc.php" id="create_customer" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input type="hidden" name="form_type" value="create_customer" /><input type="hidden" name="utf8" value="✓" />
  <div id="first_name" class="clearfix large_form"> <label for="fname" class="login">Nome</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="fname" id="fname" class="large" size="30" />
  </div>
  <div id="last_name" class="clearfix large_form"> <label for="lname" class="login">Sobrenome</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="lname" id="lname" class="large" size="30" /></div>
  <div id="email" class="clearfix large_form"> <label for="email" class="login">E-mail</label> <input type="email" value="" name="email" id="email" class="large" size="30" /></div>
  <div id="password" class="clearfix large_form"> <label for="password" class="login">Senha</label> <input type="password" value="" name="pwd" id="password" class="large password" size="30" />
    <div id="password" class="clearfix large_form"> <label for="password" class="login">Repetir Senha</label> <input type="password" value="" name="pwd-repeat" id="password" class="large password" size="30" />
    </div>
    <div class="acceptsMarketing"> <input type="checkbox" id="customer[accepts_marketing]" name="customer[accepts_marketing]"> <label for="customer[accepts_marketing]">Assine a nossa
                    newsletter?</label></div>
    <div class="action_bottom"> <input class="btn action_button" name="signup-submit" type="submit" value="Inscrever-se" />
      <p class="right" style="padding-top: 8px;">
        <input class="btn action_button" type="submit" value="Recuperar Senha" />
        <p class="right" style="padding-top: 8px;">
          Já é cliente? <a href="login.php" id="customer_login_link">Entrar →</a></p>
    </div>
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['signup-submit'])){
    require 'dbh.inc.php';

    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];
    $pwdrepeat = $_POST['pwd-repeat'];

    if(empty($fname) || empty($lname) || empty($email) || empty($password) || empty($passwordrepeat)) {
        header("Location: ../register.php?error=emptyfields&fname=".$fname."&lname".$lname."&email".$email."&pwd".$pwd."&pwdrepeat".$pwdrepeat);
        exit();
    }

    else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $fname))
    {
        header("Location: ../register.php?error=invalidmail&email=".$email);
        exit();
    }
    else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $lname))
    {
        header("Location: ../register.php?error=invalidmail&email=".$email);
        exit();
    }
    else if($pwd !== $pwdrepeat){
        header("Location: ../register.php?error=passwordcheck&fname=".$fname."&lname".$lname);
        exit();
    }
    else{
        $sql = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email=?";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
            header("Location: ../register.php?error=signuperror");
        exit();
        }
        else{
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $email);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
        $resultCheck = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
            if($resultCheck > 0){
            header("Location: ../register.php?error=signuperrorUserTaken&email=".$email);
            exit();
            }
            else{
                $sql = "INSERT INTO users (fname, lname, email, pwd) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
                $stmt = mysqli_Stmt_init($conn);
                if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
                    header("Location: ../signup.phperror=sqlerror");
                    exit();
                }
                else{
                    $hashedPwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $fname, $lname, $email, $pwd);
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                    header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=success");
                    exit();
                }
            }
        }
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        mysqli_close($conn);
    }
}
else{
    header("Location: ../signup.php");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: _**Never ever** ever never_ store passwords in plain text! You should _always_ hash the passwords using [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and only store the hashes. Then you can use [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to verify a password against a hash.

Comment: `$pwd` and `$pwdrepeat` are not the same variables as `$password` and `$passwordrepeat`

Comment: Your html is invalid - you have unclosed elements ( div and p ) towards the end

Comment: In your code have 2 mistakes 1. is you by mistakenly add name "signup-submit" to div instead of submit button and 2. is  assign variable to $pwd and check if condition $password  same for $pwdrepeat  assigned and check with $passwordrepeat

Comment: <div class="action_bottom"> <input class="btn action_button" name="signup-submit" type="submit" value="Inscrever-se" />. In-fact what was wrong was just the naming mistakes for the variables that i just failed miserably to find, the divs alright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
$pwdrepeat = $_POST['pwd-repeat'];

if(empty($fname) || empty($lname) || empty($email) || empty($password) || empty($passwordrepeat)) {
```

You assign `$_POST['pwd-repeat']` to `$pwdrepeat`, but you check `empty($passwordrepeat)`. `$passwordrepeat` is never set, which means `empty($passwordrepeat)` is always true. This makes the entire `if` condition always true.

Comment: Yes, the same was true for the password, i messed it up because originally, password was a selected word while inserting into mysql, thanks a bunch!